# Can anyone chant below Krishna mantra without initiation?

Tags: vishnu, mantras

Namo gopinjavallabhyam

Gopijanvallabha charnau Sharanam prapadaye

These  two mantras are from sanat kumara sanhita, where siva tells to narada that any one can chant these mantra without any restriction and rules,

My question is can anyone chant these mantras without initiation?

Comment: When Shiva himself said what more you need for confirmation ?